# how can I call an enumerator from keyboard?

Tags: c++

I've just started to learn C++ recently, and I'm wondering if I can call an enumerator by typing its name on keyboard or not. Pls help. Sorry if I make any grammar mistake.

```
int main()
{
    enum MonsterRaces
    {
        orcs = 1,
        goblins l = 2,
        trolls = 3,
    };

    std::cout << "Enter your monster race: ";
    std::string x;
    std::getline(std::cin, x);

    MonsterRaces yourPick = x;

    std::cout << "You've picked races numbered: " << yourPick;
    return 0;
}
```

it prints

> "cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'main()::MonsterRaces' in initialization"

Comment: cause you tried ‘enum’(int) initialization using ‘string’

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use enum with user input in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866701/how-to-use-enum-with-user-input-in-c)

Comment: Use a `std::map` or other similar lookup to convert a user entered string into an enum value.

Comment: Maybe you can use `switch`

Comment: @AndrásElKoulali `switch` only works for limited types, e.g. integers.  It doesn't work for strings

Comment: @Quang Đại Nguyễn what happens if the user writes "banana" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `std::map`.  Put this somewhere:

```
const std::map<std::string, int> table {
    {"orcs"   , 1},
    {"goblins", 2},
    {"trolls" , 3},
};
```

and then use

```
std::cout << table.at(yourPick);
```